# SFMC_SSJS : Could we Update\Delete an automation from a different BU?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs

I am trying to Update\Delete an automation from the parent BU (the automation in question is in a child BU).

I have tried with 2 methdos :

Method_1 :

```
        var api = new Script.Util.WSProxy();

        api.setClientId({
            "ID": targetMID,
            "UserID": Platform.Function.AuthenticatedEmployeeID()
        });

        var result = api.deleteItem("Automation", { 
            CustomerKey: checkAutomationExistsCustomerKey
        });
```

But I am getting this message :

```
        "StatusCode": "Error",
        "StatusMessage": "Exception occurred during [DeleteProgram] ErrorID: 1143461128",
```

Method_2:
[https://mcXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/automation/v1/automations/{{programID}}](https://mcXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/automation/v1/automations/%7B%7BprogramID%7D%7D)
But I am getting a message saying that
Delete method is not implemented

Could someone help me please ? :) :)

Comment: Try with just the MID, it should work to impersonate a child bu from parent: `api.setClientId({"ID": 12345});` (assuming the rest of your script works ok)

Comment: Hello @zuzannamj,

Thanks a lot for your help :) :).

Yes, I tried with the MID of the child BU. 
It has worked well to :

- Create, Update and Delete Activities (Script and Filters) in the Child BU
- Create an Automation in the Child BU
 
- But not to Update or Delete an automation in the Child BU :/

So I tried with a  a twisted method (thanks to the legacy endpoints) : 

Each time I want to update an automation in the Child BU :
1- I create a Script (the same one that doesn't work from the mother BU) in the Child BU.
2- Then I launch it
3- And finally I delete it

Answer (score 0):

1- Check if script Exists

```
    var endpoint = "https://XXXX.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/automation/v1/scripts?$page=1&$pageSize=10&$filter=name eq " + scriptActivityToBeCreatedName;
    request.method = "GET";
```

2- Deleted if it exists

```
    var endpoint = "https://XXXX.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/automation/v1/scripts/" + scriptActivityToBeCreatedID; 
    request.method = "DELETE";
```

3- Create it

```
Platform.Load("core", "1.1");

var targetMID = XXXX;
var sourceMID = XXXX;

var scriptActivityToBeCreatedName = "DEV_DELETE_XXXXXXX";
var scriptActivityToBeCreatedCustomerKey = "DEV_DELETE_XXXXXX";

var automationToBeDeletedCustomerKey = "DEV_XXXXXX";
var url = "https:/XXXX.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/automation/v1/scripts/";
var contentType = 'application/json';
var contentPayload = {
    "name": scriptActivityToBeCreatedName,
    "key": scriptActivityToBeCreatedCustomerKey,
    "description": "",
    "script": "<script runat='server'> \n    Platform.Load('core', '1.1'); \n    var sourceMID = " + sourceMID + "; \n   var targetMID = " + targetMID + "; \n   var automationCustomerKey = '" + automationToBeDeletedCustomerKey + "'; \n   var proxDelete = new Script.Util.WSProxy(); \n  proxDelete.setClientId({ 'ID': targetMID }); \n     var result = proxDelete.deleteItem('Automation', { CustomerKey: automationCustomerKey }); \n    </script>",
    "categoryId": XXXX //1.1.1 Segments
  };
    request.method = "POST";
```

4- Launch it

```
    var endpoint = "https://XXXXXXX4.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/automation/v1/scripts/" + scriptID + "/start";
    request.method = "POST";
```